# Capturar valor de checkbox deshabilidatos

Tags: html, jquery

Tengo checkbox deshabilitados, los cuales los "checkeo" con una función, sin embargo al chekearlos o deschekearlos quiero que se siga manteniendo su propiedad de disabled true, solo que al momento de enviar la data jquery no me toma los valores seleccionados,es decir los inputs disableds no son tomados en cuenta, ¿cómo haría para capturar esos valores?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basandose en la [pregunta anterior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7834293/4987172):

> Firefox, y tal vez otros navegadores, deshabilitan eventos DOM en campos de formulario que están deshabilitados. Cualquier evento que se inicia en el campo de formulario deshabilitado se cancela completamente y no se propaga hasta el árbol DOM. Corregirme si estoy equivocado, pero si hace clic en el botón desactivado, el origen del evento es el botón deshabilitado y el evento de clic se borra completamente. El navegador literalmente no sabe que el botón se ha hecho clic, ni pasa el evento de clic en. Es como si estuvieras haciendo clic en un agujero negro en la página web.

Por lo anterior, el metodo `click` no responde en los elementos `disabled`.Esto se puede arreglar envolviendo el checkbox en un div:

```js
$("#sub-div").click(function(){
 var type = $(this).children('input').attr("type");
  if ( type === "checkbox" )
  {
    var estado = $(this).children('#dd').prop("checked");
    $(this).children('input').prop( "checked", !estado);
  }
});
```

```css
#sub-div{
    background-color : #ccc;
    color : #a21;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 1px solid #73AD21;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sub-div">
  <input type="checkbox" name="valor" value="valor" id="dd" disabled > Un valor<br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

utilicé un viejo truco, por si a alguien le pueda servir.

```js
$($('input[name="cnSelects"]').prop("disabled",false));
alert($('input[name="cnSelects"]:checked').serialize());
$($('input[name="cnSelects"]').prop("disabled",true));
```

lo que hago es ponerlos enableds envío la data y luego vuelvo y los coloco disabled

Answer (score 0):

El método **prop()** sirve para modificar propiedades nativas de **Javascript** de los elementos de una página.
En principio, enviando un único parámetro nos sirve para acceder al valor de una propiedad, aquella que indiquemos en el parámetro. La otra opción nos sirve para modificar una propiedad y para ello debemos indicar dos parámetros, el primero sería la propiedad a modificar y el segundo el valor que queremos introducir.

**`$(elemento).prop("checked");`**

Esto nos devolvería el valor de la propiedad **Javascript** "**checked**", que seguramente sepamos, es un booleano que indica con true o false si un campo checkbox está o no marcado.

Si quisiéramos modificar el estado del **checkbox**, hacemos lo siguiente:

**`$(elemento).prop("checked", true);`**

Esto haría que el **checkbox** estuviera marcado como confirmado.

Y en caso a la propiedad **disabled**, seria de la siguiente manera:

```
$(elemento).prop("disabled", true);
```